# How to move globbed gulp.src files into a nested gulp.dest folder

Tags: gulp, glob, gulp-watch, gulp-dest

**QUESTION PART 1: OUTPUTTING TO A NESTED DYNAMIC FOLDER**

I use **Gulp.js** for **graphic email development.** My employer is switching to a different marketing platform which requires our email templates to be in a different folder structure. **I'm having trouble outputting to nested folders when gulp.src uses globbing.** I'd appreciate your help!

Here is a simplified example the gulp.src folder:

```
build/template1/template1.html
build/template2/template2.html
build/template3/template4.html
build/template4/template4.html
```

Here is a simplified example the gulp.src folder:

```
build/template1/theme/html/template1.html
build/template2/theme/html/template2.html
build/template3/theme/html/template4.html
build/template4/theme/html/template4.html
```

I want to do something like a wildcard for the dynamic template folders ...

```
gulp.task('moveFile', function(){
  return gulp.src('./build/*/*.html')
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/*/theme/html'));
});
```

... But globbing only works in the gulp.src. **How can I output to a dynamic folder when using a globbed gulp.src?** the closest I can get is putting the /theme folder at the same level as the template folders, not inside each as desired.

Thank you for your help!

**QUESTION PART 2: OUTPUTTING A *RENAMED FILE* TO A NESTED DYNAMIC FOLDER**

Mark's answered my question (Thanks @Mark!), but I over-simplified my use case so I'm adding a Part 2.

In addition to nesting the file, I need to rename it. (I had this part working originally, but can't get the 2 parts to work together.) Referring to the gulp-rename documentation, I made 3 different attempts. It's so close but I'd appreciate a little more help. :-)

```
// ATTEMPT 1: Using gulp-rename mutating function method
gulp.task('createTwig', function(){
  return gulp.src('./build/*/*.html')
    .pipe(rename(
      function (path) {
        path.basename = "email";
        path.extname = ".html.twig";
      },
      function (file) {
        console.log(file.dirname);
        file.dirname = nodePath.join(file.dirname, 'theme/html');
      }
    ))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
});

// ATTEMPT 2: Using gulp-rename fixed object method
gulp.task('createTwig', function(){
  return gulp.src('./build/*/*.html', { base: process.cwd() })
    .pipe(rename(
      {
        basename: "email",
        extname: ".html.twig"
      },
      function (file) {
        console.log(file.dirname);
        file.dirname = nodePath.join(file.dirname, 'theme/html');
      }
    ))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
});

// ATTEMPT 3: Using gulp-rename mutating function method
gulp.task('createTwig', function(){
  return gulp.src('./build/*/*.html')
    .pipe(rename(
      function (path, file) {
        path.basename = "email";
        path.extname = ".html.twig";
        console.log(file.dirname);
        file.dirname = nodePath.join(file.dirname, 'theme/html');
      }
    ))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
const rename = require("gulp-rename");
const path = require("path");


gulp.task('moveFile', function(){
  return gulp.src(['build/**/*.html'])

    .pipe(rename(function (file) {
      console.log(file.dirname);
      file.dirname = path.join(file.dirname, 'theme/html');
    }))

    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))   // build/template1/theme/html
});
```

I tried a few ways, including trying the `base` option and `gulp-flatten` and using a function in `gulp.dest` but this was the easiest.

---

Question Part #2:

```
gulp.task('createTwig', function(){
  return gulp.src(['build/**/*.html'])

  .pipe(rename(function (file) {

    file.basename = "email";
    file.extname = ".html.twig";
  
    file.dirname = path.join(file.dirname, 'theme/html');
  }))

  .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))   // build/template1/theme/html
});
```

`path.basename/extname` are just "getters", you cannot set those values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Mark. When I tried your supplied code using the gulp-rename plugin I get a terminal error: **ReferenceError: path is not defined**. I tried adding the `path` argument to the function, but that did not help. I don't see anything else in your code that would account for the path object. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the `path` require statement - which is built-in to node, you don't need to separately install it. See https://nodejs.org/api/path.html.  I added it above.

Comment: That worked! Thanks @Mark! Could you help with one more thing? My original question was over-simplified. I added a part 2 to the question. Not only do I need to nest the file, I need to rename it. I had the renaming working fine originally, but now the two parts aren't working together as I am trying to. Thx again!

Comment: Are they all being renamed `email.html.twig`, just going into the separate directories?

Comment: Each email template has to have a file named "email.html.twig". Thanks for answering Part 2, @Mark! That did the trick. I did not (and still don't) understand why path.property is used in the gulp-rename docs, but file.property seems interchangeable.